# General instructions after parachain block authoring is stuck

Tags: parachain

I'm wondering if there's any general instruction guidance when parachain block authoring is somehow stuck. I understand the relaychain network might need to do something to help parachain get out of the situation (e.g. clearing out the stuck blocks), but what should we do on the parachain side?

The question originates from the situation where last week on rococo-parachain I have had a runtime upgrade which stopped the parachain blocks from being produced, the reason is unclear as the built wasm was tested OK on the staging testnet and the new wasm itself is just a trivial change to `baseCallFilter`. I have contacted the rococo admin to ask them to clean up the stuck block if possible. After that I'm still struggling to get the blocks authoring working (it worked once, but even then it started from block #0, so all the previous states were lost).

Therefore I'm curious if there's any **guidance or handbook** to follow when such a situation happens. I understand the root cause behind it could be various, but maybe there's a more concrete and detailed procedure that we can do from parachain side (especially in production env), so that:

- it preserves all the historical state
- it can continue authoring blocks after the relaychain fixes the block

The guidance could include things like:

- DB backup and restore?
- which parachain DB is safe to clear (collator/rpc/bootnode node)?
- what's the order of clearing and restarting the collator/rpc nodes usually?
- How to debug if still no blocks can be produced?
- ...

If it's hard to list the steps to cover all cases, maybe some general principles would help too (DOs and DONTs). I highly appreciate any help!

Comment: I would like to tackle some of the ending questions, even though perhaps it would make more sense to create specific Qs in stackexchange for each of them.

- safest DB to clear ?: My two cents here is that it doesn't make a difference from the perspective of the node, as if it has not the history it will start importing blocks from others.

- How to debug block production on parachains: Here it might be helpfull keeping the logs, but activating trace for `cumulus-collator` target by adding `-lcumulus-collator=trace` to your lunch script.

Comment: Also, worth mentioning that the relaychain is expecting from the parachain blocks built on top of the last block it has been finalized. If you have removed collators DBs while running, and they are starting from scratch again, relaychain won't be able to finalize blocks because the parachain nodes are building on top of something different to what is expected from the validators (relaychain) point of view.